# GitHub pages "save" buttons is not getting enabled even after selecting "main" branch

Tags: github, github-pages

Is this a bug with GH pages ? As I've done similar actions many a times before

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary glitch in GitHub, it worked properly after sometime; but I had to re-load and retry same steps.

Comment: Currently dealing with this. Gotta love that there's nothing you can do in this situation. No live chat support

Comment: Long back there was something called "Quality" in software, since last decade it has disappeared in "fail fast" mentality.

Comment: I will say that I opened a ticket on the GitHub support and they solved my issue in under 24 hours. Turns out they had just rolled out a feature that created a bug in GitHub pages deployment. Not every day that you find a bug in enterprise software.